# postinstall script for dependencies(nodejs) for angular-phonecat app

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am behind a corporate firewall, so i have set the proxies for node using

> npm config set https-proxy http://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080

and for http too..

which is working fine i guess.. 
now when i do npm install , then the dependencies get downloaded , as i can see them in my node-modules folder but the postinstall script "bower install" ,it shows the following error in the cmd :

angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall C:\angular-phonecat\angular-phonecat

bower install

bower retry    Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/angular-mock
s failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.8s

So, is this error catastrophic or i can live with it . Deleting this postinstall property from the package.json file starts the server at least .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem myself.. answering it just to help newbies like myself who dont have much idea of whats going on ..

seems i had to configure proxy for bower as well which i overlooked.. 
Configure it in the .bowerrc file like this ::

{

"directory": "app/bower_components",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",

"proxy":"http ://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080/",

"https-proxy":"http ://username:password@proxy.company.com:8080/",

"strict-ssl": false

}

and if git is not in the PATH variable (happens in windows if you directly download it from the site),
then run 'bower install' from git bash ..